# The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction timeout exception for multithreading updates

Tags: multithreading, wcf, transactions, timeout, transactionscope

I am using the following transaction

```
var transactionScopeOptions = new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, Timeout = Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0) };
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionScopeOptions))
{
     /* update query here with data context execute command */
}
```

And I keep getting **The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction** exception with the inner exception of **Transaction Timeout**.

Locally I only get in 1 in 100,000 chances, but in the server it happens like every now and then. The application is running on MSMQ and WCF.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
                     ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

I have tried the following:

```
<system.transactions>
  <machineSettings maxTimeout="02:00:00" />
</system.transactions>
```

and setting the dataContext.CommandTimeout to 1 hour or 0 (infinite).
Changed the Connection Timeout=3600 in the app.config

I have tried almost everything I've read on Google but still no luck. Hope I can remove this problem in the server.

NOTE: update query usually last between 0 to 20 seconds (max) but since it's multithreading, it causes the error. If I ran the ones in the exception, it doesn't seem to get the error anymore either because the transaction doesn't time out.

**EDIT:**

All my queries have dirty read (nolock for reads and rowlock for updates)

**EDIT:**

Component Services > My Computer > Options > Transaction Timeout (seconds): 600
Then restarted "Distributed Transaction Coordinator" in services.

Still no luck

**EDIT:**

Timestamp was added when entering the transactionScope and when getting the exception (Transaction TimeOut) it seems it is not really time out related because it is kicked out less than a minute from entering the transaction scope (when I already specified the transaction to have a time out in 10 minutes).

This means it just gives out Transaction TimeOut exception even if it really didn't timed out.

**EDIT:**

Based on the last error, I tried adding the following, [based from this website](http://weblogs.asp.net/ryangaraygay/archive/2008/04/14/issue-with-system-transactions-sqlconnection-and-timeout.aspx) to my connection string:

```
Transaction Binding=Explicit Unbind
```

Though I am using SQL Server 2012 and latest Visual Studio Framework, so not sure it helps at all.

**EDIT:**

I also have the following:

In the app config:

```
<system.transactions>
    <defaultSettings timeout="2:00:00" />
</system.transactions>
```

binding services:

```
<binding  name="FooBinding"
                  deadLetterQueue="System"
                  maxReceivedMessageSize="524288"
                  exactlyOnce="true"
                  receiveErrorHandling="Move"
                  retryCycleDelay="00:00:30"
                  maxRetryCycles="120"
                  receiveRetryCount="0"
                  sendTimeout="00:01:00">
```

and

```
<serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:10:00" />
```

**EDIT:**

I tried changing the config to the following, hoping it was a WCF timeout (default is 1 minute) but still get those exceptions: (extend timeout to 10 minutes)

```
<binding  name="FooBinding"
                      deadLetterQueue="System"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="524288"
                      exactlyOnce="true"
                      receiveErrorHandling="Move"
                      retryCycleDelay="00:00:30"
                      maxRetryCycles="120"
                      receiveRetryCount="0"
                      closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                      openTimeout="00:10:00"
                      receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                      sendTimeout="00:10:00" />
```

I asked a [related question with some code logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630900/getting-transaction-timeout-exceptions-not-valid-for-the-state-of-the-transacti) in another link.